# Change button background colour in a row of buttons in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have 3 buttons rendered for each item of an array and I want to be able to toggle the background colour of the buttons. However, only one button should change its background colour in a row.

If a button in a row is already clicked and it's background colour is changed, when a new button on that row is selected that button should revert to it's old background colour and the newly clicked one should change it's colour.

Here is a [stackblitz playground example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scnuvj?file=src/App.js) of the problem and what I did to try and solve it.

Comment: You should not include links to external sources, but rather include the code in your post directly. Including external references (such as links to code and screenshots of coding) is a very good way to get downvoted.

Comment: That is not true. Links to JSFiddle or other code repos are perfectly fine @LaytonGB

Comment: Only if the code is also posted on StackExchange: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have a maintain an object in state, remembering which button is active for each of the persons.

Basically add new state in your component like this.

`const [activeButtons, setActiveButtons] = useState({});`

Here `activeButtons` will be something like `{ Alexander: 1, Victoria: 2 }` indicating that. for Alexandar - the button 1 is active and for Victoria - the button 2 is active.

Then, change your click handler to this

```
const clickFunc = (name, buttonID) => {
    setActiveButtons({ ...activeButtons, [name]: buttonID });
};
```

And use it like this on all buttons

`onClick={() => clickFunc(name, 1)}`

Finally, control your `className` like this

`className={activeButtons[name] == 1 ? 'button-clicked' : 'button-unclicked'}`

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kn2c1m?file=src/App.js) for full code.

Comment: My scenario is little different please help, my click event is in parent component then how to call seActiveButtons.

Comment: Hi, if you click event is in the parent component, then the state and the setActiveButtons must also be part of the parent component. You can post another question or paste your stackblitz here for a much clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should make every card unique as a result you need to create a Card component and handle a click inside of that component.
Here is my solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rmp5mr?file=src%2FApp.js